# Postgres: Foreign key doesn't match all rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am starting to learn databases and I have problem with foreign key.

I have this two tables:

1) table with movies

```
create table movies (
    id_m  serial primary key,
    name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
    type varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    year smallint NOT NULL,
    availability smallint references availability(id_a) NOT NULL
)
```

2) table with availability

```
create table availability(
    id_a serial primary key,
    availability (varchar 20) NOT NULL,
)
```

Table movies looks like:

1. Thor Blu-Ray 2012 1
2. Avangers 2 Blu-ray 2014 2
3. Gran Torino DVD 2008 1
4. Titanic DVD 1998 2

Table availability looks like:
 1. Available
 2. unavailable

When I type this:

```
SELECT movies.id_n,movies.name,availability.availability 
FROM movies 
full outer join availability on movies.id_n = availability.id_a;
```

Availability only appears in first two columns:

1. Thor Available
2. Avangers 2  Unavailable
3. Gran Torino
4. Titanic DVD

Could you please help me how to get availability to next movies in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM movies 
join availability on movies.availability = availability.id_a;
```

Some more details: 
You joined on the pks (`movies.id_n = availability.id_a`), in most cases joins make sense along fk relationships (`movies.availability = availability.id_a`). This is all you missed. The other items are just clean-up.

I removed the unneeded `full outer` clause. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for a better understanding of the types of joins.

Finally `select *` is the equivalent of "select all columns"